# SQL query to select a row with matching one column value either of three passed column which is not empty

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have a table like this

```
--------------------------------------------------
|  ID  |  Name  |  Data1  | OPT1  | OPT2  | OPT3 |
|------------------------------------------------|
| 1    |  Bob   |  test1  |       |  B    |      |
| 2    |  Jake  |  test2  |  A    |       |      |
| 3    |  Rob   |  test3  |       |       |  C   |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I want to write sql query for condition like this

```
SELECT * FROM table 
    IF OPT1 IS NOT EMPTY
        THEN OPT1 = [PASSED_VALUE]
    IF OPT2 IS NOT EMPTY
        THEN OPT2 = [PASSES_VALUE]
    IF OPT3 IS NOT EMPTY
        THEN OPT3 = [PASSED_VALUE]
```

for e.g i want to get first row data so the sql query should match OPT2 value with "B" and do not check value in OPT1 and OPT3 if they are empty

Comment: 'The query should not check the column which is empty.' - I wonder how query can know that without testing?

Comment: @P.Salmon Actually these rows will have value in only one of these column (OPT1, OPT2, OPT3) its a user choice who is filling it, But in the application we are passing all three column to check return the row now if in first row OPT1 and OPT3 sent as blank then that condition will also true. SO i need a query which will check which column is not empty and then match the value if value matches then the row will return

Comment: edited the question to describe my problem in another way

Comment: When you say empty do you mean NULL or ''

Comment: i mean "" (empty), but if could check both null and empty then that will be great

Comment: The most relevant update to your question would be adding up your expected output. @HarishKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from table 
where coalesce(opt1,opt2,opt3) = passedvalue or
      concat(opt1,opt2,op3) = passedvalue
```

Comment: It didn't worked. Actually i have to pass all three value for OPT1, OPT2 and OPT3 because its not known that which column is having a value so this query should be check which of these column will have value and match that value with the sent value and return the row

Comment: I disagree https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90185f9c637feb5159171f015edc34f4

Comment: i have changed my logic in the code and parsing only variable which is having value in it and then your query is working fine. Accepting you answer as correct. Thank you so much for your effort